# How can I call a method in the program class?

Tags: c#

I had difficulty when I wanted to use a method from the Employee class to the Program class. My methods worked in the Program class. Will you be able to help me?

Code:

```
Class Employee{
....
public static void PrintEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        if (employees != null)
        {
            int j = 1;
            foreach (var employee in employees)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{j}. Name: {employee.Name}; Surname: {employee.Surname}; Nickname: {employee.NickName};");
                j++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please add an employee!");
        }
    }
  }
```

And class program:

```
PrintEmployees(employees);
```

the error I receive:

> The name "PrintEmployees" does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've moved that static method to its own class you need to prefix with the class name

```
 Employee.PrintEmployees(employees);
```

or you can use the [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) directive at the top of your program file

```
using static YourNamespace.Employee
```

And then you can use it as you originally attempted

```
PrintEmployees(employees);
```